# MapRequestHandler issue in IIS for .net websites

Tags: iis, iis-7

I get the following error when I try and serve css or javascript via my local iis. I am running windows 7 and iis7.

The resource you are looking for does not have a handler associated with it.

Module IIS Web Core
Notification MapRequestHandler
Handler Not yet determined
Error Code 0x80070002
Requested URL http://secure.XXXXXX:80/ols/css/global.css
Physical Path C:\XXXXXX\css\global.css
Logon Method Anonymous
Logon User Anonymous

Any ideas how i can resolve this? Issue is with css, javascript etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, was missing a StaticFile handler mapping.